# creating user through admin interface seems to try to always create at id: 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, admin

I'm attempting to have an admin section that can create users on the fly. But it seems to always error out, from the console i see:

```
Started POST "/pressroom/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-22 15:56:11 -0800
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rweuZHlkUJOL0D3GDzBD82pSEk7z+22bZ79Gsyht5Pg=", "user"=>{"email"=>"efhufh@suhs.com", "username"=>"", "firstname"=>"", "lastname"=>"", "city"=>"", "zip"=>"", "state"=>"", "country"=>"", "role_ids"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Role Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "roles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  Role Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles"
  Rendered users/_form.html.erb (14.1ms)
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/pressroom (15.3ms)
  Rendered pressroom/_presstools.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered pressroom/_header.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered pressroom/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 50ms (Views: 38.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

Not sure why it's failing but it looks like the user_id is always 1, which would be wrong as i already have 2 users in the db of user_id 1 and 2. The error is the ROLLBACK. Below is my routes for this section.

```
get 'pressroom/accounts/new' => 'users#new', :as => :admin_new_user
post 'pressroom/accounts/new' => 'users#create'
```

and my new and create functions from users_controller:

```
def new
    @user = User.new
 end

def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      redirect_to users_admin_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
      redirect_to users_admin_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
    end
  end

def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user_params])

    if @user.save
      redirect_to users_admin_path, notice: 'User was successfully created.'
    else
      redirect_to users_admin_path, :alert => "Unable to create user."
    end
  end
```

And here is my form that is making the call:

```
<div class="panel-body">

    <%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control", :autofocus => true %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :username %>
        <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :firstname %>
        <%= f.text_field :firstname, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :lastname %>
        <%= f.text_field :lastname, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :city %>
        <%= f.text_field :city, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :zip %>
        <%= f.text_field :zip, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :state %>
        <%= f.text_field :state, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :country %>
        <%= f.text_field :country, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <h3>Change Role</h3>
      <%= f.input :role_ids, :collection => Role.all, :as => :radio_buttons, :label_method => lambda {|t| t.name.titleize}, :label => false, :item_wrapper_class => 'inline', checked: @user.role_ids.first %>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Comment: You're doing something wrong, but without seeing your code it's impossible to say *what*. Also, you're talking about an error, but I don't see an error anywhere.

Comment: i've added some code, sorry about that.

Comment: You posted your `update` action. What does your `create` action look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from your log, the user params are in `params[:user]`:

```
"user"=>{"email"=>"efhufh@suhs.com", # Etc.
```

but in your `create` action you are using `params[:user_params]`, which is `nil`. Therefore no user is created.

Apparently you're using [Strong Parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) and you're returning the permitted parameters from a method. In that case you should pass the method like this:

```
User.new(user_params)
```

Comment: Doing that gives me a ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError on `@user = User.new(params[:user])` I have at the bottom of my usercontroller the following: `def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :salt, :encrypted_password, :role_ids, :firstname, :lastname, :city, :zip, :state, :country )
  end`

Comment: Then you should do `User.new(user_params)`, instead of `User.new(params[:user_params])`.

Comment: using that still fails, i've added my form just to see if i made a mistake there.

Comment: got it, needed the password field. Thanks!